# constructor in the java enumeration datatype

Tags: java

```
package myPackage;
enum CarDemo {
    MARUTI(1), SUXIKI(2),GALIOK(4);
    String st;
    int i;
    CarDemo(String st){
        this.st=st;
    }
    CarDemo(int i){
        this.i=i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public class Car{
        public static void main(String a[]){
            CarDemo s =CarDemo.MARUTI;  
        }
}
```

/*when i have executed this program and it's displaying entire values of enum constants.Is the enum constructor is called for three times during the creation of the enum type  in the main method?*/

Answer (score 1):

[Enum Members (JLS-8.9.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), has this (among other things) to say -

> An enum constant is said to be created when the corresponding implicitly declared field is initialized.

So, when your `main()` runs and initializes `s` with `CarDemo s = CarDemo.MARUTI;` all of the members are *created*.